# Is it possible for SQL to make a SELECT from a "list"? Example inside

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

My tables as follows

```
name
| id | name |
|  1 | jon  |
|  2 | mary |

skill
| id | skill | level |
|  1 | C++   | 3     |
|  1 | Java  | 2     |
|  1 | HTML  | 5     |
|  1 | CSS   | 4     |
|  1 | JS    | 5     |
|  2 | PHP   | 4     |
|  2 | Ruby  | 3     |
|  2 | Perl  | 1     |
```

So I want the output to be like this:

```
| name | skill_1 | lv_1 | skill_2 | lv_2 | skill_3 | lv_3 | skill_4 | lv_4 | skill_5 | lv_5 |
| jon  | C++     | 3    | Java    | 2    | HTML    | 5    | CSS     | 4    | JS      | 5    |
| mary | PHP     | 4    | Ruby    | 3    | Perl    | 1    |         |      |         |      |
```

What type of join or union statements would I be using? Each person has only 5 skills max.

So how would the SQL for this look like? Is it even possible?

I'm completely lost and have no idea where to start.

Comment: Search for "pivot" this is being asked once a week.

Comment: MySQL does not have a pivot function I believe.

Comment: You are right it doesn't. But the technique itself is called pivot and there are ways to do it in MySQL as well. SO even has a tag for that. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+pivot

Comment: this question really deserve upvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that a `Name` can have a maximum of `5 Skills`, this problem can be done using static query.

```
-- <<== PART 2
SELECT  Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN Skill END) Skill_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 2 THEN Skill END) Skill_2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 3 THEN Skill END) Skill_3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 4 THEN Skill END) Skill_4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 5 THEN Skill END) Skill_5
FROM
        ( -- <<== PART 1
            SELECT  a.Name, 
                    b.Skill,
                    (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*)
                        FROM    Skill c
                        WHERE   c.id = b.id AND
                                c.Skill <= b.Skill) AS RowNumber
            FROM    Name a
                    INNER JOIN Skill b
                        ON a.id = b.id
        ) x
GROUP   BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/909b1/4)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ NAME ║ SKILL_1 ║ SKILL_2 ║ SKILL_3 ║ SKILL_4 ║ SKILL_5 ║
╠══════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ jon  ║ C++     ║ CSS     ║ HTML    ║ Java    ║ JS      ║
║ mary ║ Perl    ║ PHP     ║ Ruby    ║ (null)  ║ (null)  ║
╚══════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

**BRIEF EXPLANATION**

Let's breakdown it down. There are two parts in the query.

The first part, which is **PART 1**, of the query generates the sequence of number on `Skill` for every `Name`. It just uses correlated subquery to mimic a window function `ROW_NUMBER` which `MySQL` does not support.

- [Generating Sequential Number on Skill (SQLFiddle Demo)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/909b1/5)

The second part, **PART 2**, transpose the rows into columns based on the sequential number generated on **PART 1**. It uses `CASE` to test the value of the number and returns the `Skill` associated on the number. If the number does not match it returns a `NULL` value. Next, it aggregates the column for every group of `Name` using `MAX()` so `SKILL` will be returned instead of `NULL` if there is any.

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN Skill END) Skill_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN Level END) Level_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 2 THEN Skill END) Skill_2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 2 THEN Level END) Level_2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 3 THEN Skill END) Skill_3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 3 THEN Level END) Level_3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 4 THEN Skill END) Skill_4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 4 THEN Level END) Level_4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 5 THEN Skill END) Skill_5,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = 5 THEN Level END) Level_5
FROM
        (
            SELECT  a.Name, 
                    b.Skill,
                    (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*)
                        FROM    Skill c
                        WHERE   c.id = b.id AND
                                c.skill <= b.skill) AS RowNumber,
                    b.Level
            FROM    Name a
                    INNER JOIN Skill b
                        ON a.id = b.id
        ) x
GROUP   BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7915b/8)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ NAME ║ SKILL_1 ║ LEVEL_1 ║ SKILL_2 ║ LEVEL_2 ║ SKILL_3 ║ LEVEL_3 ║ SKILL_4 ║ LEVEL_4 ║ SKILL_5 ║ LEVEL_5 ║
╠══════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ jon  ║ C++     ║       3 ║ CSS     ║       4 ║ HTML    ║       5 ║ Java    ║ 2       ║ JS      ║ 5       ║
║ mary ║ Perl    ║       1 ║ PHP     ║       4 ║ Ruby    ║       3 ║ (null)  ║ (null)  ║ (null)  ║ (null)  ║
╚══════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks. I have 5 minutes to accept the answer so I want to make sure I understand: say my `skill` table had another column `level`, how would I modify so my output is now `| name | skill_1 | lv_1 | skill_2 | lv_2 | skill_3 | lv_3 | skill_4 | lv_4 | skill_5 | lv_5 |`?

Comment: @meiryo it's hard to understand the output in the comment, can you post it along with your question?

Comment: ok sure, done. It's basically adding a new column to the selection.

Comment: oh, it will now the query. let me update it.

Answer (score 2):

This could also be the possible solution!

**Query**

```
select a.name, 
(select skill  from skill where skill.id=a.id limit 0,1  ) as skill_1,
(select skill  from skill where skill.id=a.id limit 1,1) skill_2,
(select skill from skill where skill.id=a.id limit 2,1 ) skill_3,
(select skill from skill where skill.id=a.id limit 3,1) skill_4,
(select skill from skill  where skill.id=a.id limit 4,1) skill_5
 from name a
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I understand your after what is called a [pivot table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table), there is a nice tutorial [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78). In order to achive what you are after, you would need to change the schema of the `skill` table slightly to...

```
| id | skill_id | skill |
|  1 | 1        | C++   |
|  1 | 2        | Java  |
|  1 | 3        | HTML  |
|  1 | 4        | CSS   |
|  1 | 5        | PHP   |
|  2 | 1        | RUBY  |
|  2 | 2        | PERL  |
|  2 | 3        | JS    |
```

try this:

```
SELECT n.name,
, if(s.skill_id=1, s.skill, '') as 'skill_1'
, if(s.skill_id=2, s.skill, '') as 'skill_2'
, if(s.skill_id=3, s.skill, '') as 'skill_3'
, if(s.skill_id=4, s.skill, '') as 'skill_4'
, if(s.skill_id=5, s.skill, '') as 'skill_5'
FROM name n
INNER JOIN skill s ON n.id = s.id
group by s.skill
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: That is not what the OP is looking for

Comment: I'm quite sure this won't get the end resut the OP wants, but its a step in the right direction.

Comment: What does the picture have to do with the question here? Totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think in no join can answer this type of output so it is better to handle from code but you can use 
`group_concat()` with `group by`